# How can I make the head start at zero again for each iteration?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to do a FIFO paging algorithm with a given page reference string.  The program should go through page frames 1-4 and say how many page faults there were for that run-through.  It should look like this:

```
"For x page frames:
          FIFO had ### page faults.
          LRU had ### page faults."
```

(I'll be working on the LRU next).

I'm close, but the "head" in the fifo() method does not reset for each time through.  I've experimented with a few places where I say "head = 0;" and nothing is working.  I think I need another set of eyes. Does anyone see how can I make the head start at zero again for each iteration? Thanks in advance for help!

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Testfifo3 {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Testfifo3 tf3 = new Testfifo3();
        int[] array2 = {7,0,1,2,0,3,0}; //,4,2,3,0,3,2,1,2,0,1,7,0,1};  (testing with a shorter sample)
        int[] frames = {1, 2, 3, 4}; //, 5, 6, 7};  (testing with a shorter sample)
        //run the algorithms with array2:
        //print out the array you'll be using.
        System.out.println("Your string of pages is: ");    
        for (int i: array2){
            System.out.print(i + " ");          
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(int fr: frames){
            System.out.println("frames: " + fr);    
            tf3.fifo(array2, fr);
            tf3.lru(array2);
        }

    }


public void fifo(int[] arr, int fr){
        int faults = 0;  //count faults 
        int[] frames = new int [fr];  //array to hold page frames   

        //start all the frames out at -1 (because "null" gives us a null pointer reference)
        for (int c = 0; c<frames.length; c++){
            frames[c] = -1;
        }           

        int head = 0; //points to frame we need to add to

        //nested loop for comparing frame contents with pages
        //for each item in the page ref array, you'll loop through all the pages to compare
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){                    
            for(int j= 0; j < frames.length; j++){
                if (frames[j] == arr[i]){ //if the value in frames[j] equals value of page ref
                    frames[j] = arr[i]; //don't really change anything
                    break;
                }

                if (arr[i] != frames[j]){
                    frames[head] = arr[i];  //put this page ref value into head frame
                    if (head == frames.length -1){ //if head gets to the last page
                        head = 0;  //reset head back at first frame
                    }
                    else{
                        head++; //increment head    
                    }                       
                    faults++; //increment page faults
                    break; //go to next number in reference string
                }
            }   
            System.out.println("Head: " +head);
        }               
        System.out.println("\n\t"+"FIFO has "+ faults +" page faults\n");   
    }           
}
```

This as-is prints (the "Head" print statements are just for testing):

```
Your string of pages is: 
7 0 1 2 0 3 0 
frames: 1
Head: 0
Head: 0
Head: 0
Head: 0
Head: 0
Head: 0
Head: 0

    FIFO has 7 page faults


    LRU has xxxxx  page faults

frames: 2
Head: 1
Head: 0
Head: 1
Head: 0
Head: 1
Head: 0
Head: 0

    FIFO has 6 page faults


    LRU has xxxxx  page faults

frames: 3
Head: 1
Head: 2
Head: 0
Head: 1
Head: 2
Head: 0
Head: 1

    FIFO has 7 page faults


    LRU has xxxxx  page faults

frames: 4
Head: 1
Head: 2
Head: 3
Head: 0
Head: 1
Head: 2
Head: 2

    FIFO has 6 page faults


    LRU has xxxxx  page faults
```

Head should always start at zero

Comment: Doing it by-hand, I think for 3 page frames, the head should be :  0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that this code returns `head=0` only:

```
            if (arr[i] != frames[j]){
                frames[head] = arr[i];  //put this page ref value into head frame
                if (head == frames.length -1){ //if head gets to the last page
                    head = 0;  //reset head back at first frame
                }
                else{
                    head++; //increment head    
                }                       
                faults++; //increment page faults
                break; //go to next number in reference string
            }
```

If the conditions are met, `head` gets incremented. The `break` ends the `if` statement only, and can be removed.

Comment: By that 'break', I think he wanted 'continue' instead. Anyway, since the loop meets it end, like you said, can be removed.

Comment: When I take the break statement out, the page references loop as many times as the frames... So 1 frames = 7 0 1 2 0 3 0 ,  2 frames = 7 7 0 0 1 1 2 2 0 0 3 3 0 0 ,  3 frames loops: 7 7 7 0 0 0  1 1 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0...etc....

Comment: I am not saying your code will be correct, I am just identifying where it does not make sense. I do not see any FIFO in this code at all yet (sorry).

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I voted your answer up, but it doesn't show because I'm too new.